# How to conditionally read elements in LINQToXML

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

How would I go about creating my desired list by using LINQToXml?
I am close with both attempts so far.
  I should be able to do this without creating to separate queries right?

This is my XML:

```
<main>
  <cars>
    <car name="Honda">
      <feature door="4" name="Accord" />
      <feature door="2" name="Civic"/>
      <feature door="4" name="CRV"/>
    </car>
    <car name="Ford"/>
    <car name="Kia"/>
    <car name="Subaru">
      <feature door="4" name="Outback"/>
      <feature door="4" name="Legacy"/>
    </car>
  </cars>
</main>
```

Attempt #1

This will return the first car with feature.

```
var listCars = (from c in doc.Root.Descendants("cars")
select new Car
{
   Model = (p.Element("car") != null) ? p.Element("car").Attribute("name").Value : null,
   Door = (p.Element("car") != null) ? p.Element("car").Attribute("door").Value : null,
   Name = p.Attribute("name").Value
}).ToList();
```

Attempt #2

This will return all of the cars that have features

Ford and Kia would be missing

```
var cars = from c in doc.Root.Descendants("cars")
select c;

var listPermissions = (from c in cars.Descendants("car")
let cName = p.Parent.Attribute("name").Value
select new Car
{
  Model = p.Attribute("name").Value,
  Door = p.Attribute("door").Value,
  Name = pgn
}).ToList();
```

What I am trying to do is to create a list of cars that look like:

Honda, 4, Accord

Honda, 2, Civic

Honda, 4, CRV

Ford, null, null

Kia, null, null

Subaru, 4, Outback

Subaru, 4, Legacy

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have `Car` contain a list of doors and name, rather than trying to flatten it all out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a LEFT JOIN in LINQ as outlined on [101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9).

```
var makes =
    (from doc in document.Root.Descendants("cars").Descendants("car")
     join f in document.Root.Descendants("cars").Descendants("car").Descendants("feature") 
       on doc.Attribute("name").Value.ToLowerInvariant() equals f.Parent.Attribute("name").Value.ToLowerInvariant() into ps
     from f in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new
        {
            Model = doc.Attribute("name").Value,
            Door = f == null ? string.Empty : f.Attribute("door").Value,
            Name = f == null ? string.Empty : f.Attribute("name").Value
        })
    .ToList();
```